# Why doesn't Eclipse update to Juno SR2?

Tags: eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Juno SR1. Service Release 2, SR2, was released a couple weeks ago. When I click Help / Check for Updates, though, it says "No updates found". Why?

Do I need to do a clean reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The update, for some reason, does not work. However the solution is easy:

1. Help
2. Install New Software
3. Enter the URL http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2 in "Work with"
4. Select "Juno SR1 Patches"
5. Click "Next" and accept the license
6. Finish

[Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Juno_Performance_Investigation) outlines these steps. I am guessing that they want only those that are affected by the performance problems to install the patch willingly.

Comment: Thanks. I'd prefer to install SR2, though. I tried this scheme and selected "Eclipse platform" as the new software to install, but it failed with the error "Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency". It did not identify the dependency.

Comment: @ccleve you need to select "Juno SR1 Patches" from the list as identified in the Eclipse Wiki I gave in the answer. I have done this and it installed correctly. I did not try installing the "Eclipse Platform".

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows-> preferences -> Install/Update-> select uninstall/Update 
Then Select current version and click update. This will update to Service Release 2 (SR2)